# Why is it that teenagers were immune to the virus before the virus came into existance?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

In the **Maze Runner**, we know the back story of it is that there are hundreds of immunes.

Thomas is one of them, there are many in the maze trials, but there are also non-immune Gladers such as Newt.
What I do understand is that the *Flare Virus* was engineered by humans to in fact kill many people to ease the stress of the Earth as it was holding more than it could supply. That was the point of the human-made virus.

Why is it that if this virus was engineered by humans...why are teenagers, adults that have lived before the sun flares hit the Earth and babies ***naturally immune*** to this virus?

Comment: I don't know why for the plot of the story, but this kind of thing is biologically feasible - medical research is often critiqued for only being tested on a limited variety of human subjects, and results don't always extend to all humans. If tested only on a few older males for instance, women/children or other groups of untested humans might be biologically different enough that a virus or medicine behaves differently for them (not necessarily as strong as complete immunity in practice, but still *different*).

Comment: could you put this as an answer if possible? it is a possible answer.

Comment: The problem is that I have never seen the series or read the book, and an answer from canon might be found there. My comment is just conjecture from real-world science.

Comment: Ah yeah ok, no worries then.